# ANDROID locationManager.requestLocationUpdates cannot be resolved?

Tags: android, import, geolocation, location, locationmanager

I don't understand why locationManager.requestLocationUpdates  cannot be resolved. I searched up the answer and it says you must import LocationClient which is not in use anymore.

Here is how I find my current location method. Please tell me if I am missing anything.

```
 private void setUpMap() {
    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);



    LocationListener locationChangeListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
            if (l != null) {
                Log.i("SuperMap", "Location changed : Lat: " + l.getLatitude() + " Lng: " +
                        l.getLongitude());
            }
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String p) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String p) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String p, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,0,0,locationChangeListener);



    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // set map type
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    // Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    // Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Show the current location in Google Map
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!").snippet("Consider yourself located"));
}
```

}

Here are my imports

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingApi;
```

Answer (score 7):

Import `LocationListener` interface from `android.location` package because currently you are importing from `com.google.android.gms.location` package but `requestLocationUpdates` method takes `android.location.LocationListener` as last parameter.

Change :

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

to

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
```